# webapp using googleapis, uploaded file can't be found on drive but can download via api

Tags: google-drive-api, service-accounts

Using google-drive-api for i can upload and download files but when i go to google drive can not find my files in upload folder,

all of this works when i run my MVC code from localhost i.e. can find files after they are uploaded via google-drive-api

Although when running in EKS  upload / download works via google-drive-api but can't find files in drive when i login to my google-drive.

Please guide for google drive service account and MVC code (service account permission) .

Comment: Do a file.list from your code can you see your files there